# CSS Drop Down Menu Not working

Tags: css

i'm learning the basic of CSS and trying to create a dropdown menu, i tried creating a dropdown menu using plain CSS, but it's not working.

So far I tried this code:

**CSS**

```
<!-- because of the * default code it takes out all margin and padding or idententation -->
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;}

body
{
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: ABC;
    padding: 50px;
}

h1
{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/*rules for navigation menu */
/*============================================*/
ul#navmenu, ul.sub1
{
    list-style-type: none;<!-- sets bullets to none -->

}

ul#navmenu li
{
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: 125px;
    text- align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

ul#navmenu a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; <!-- this code makes the link a button instead  pointing specifically on the link -->
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 li
{

}

ul#navmenu .sub1 a 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover > a
{
 background-color: #CFC; <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
}

ul#navmenu li:hover a: hover
{
    background-color: #FF0;  <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
}

ul#navmenu ul.sub1
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;

}

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1
{
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Navigation Menu</h1>

<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a></li>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The dropdown menu is not working, it's not hiding the sub menus, i don't know why.

Here is the picture screenshot using Internet Explorer:

[IE](http://s23.postimg.org/jrzexl21n/z_IEs.png)

While using Google Chrome:

[Chrome](http://s11.postimg.org/qbo08ftlv/zchromes.png)

I can't move on:( Any suggestion why dropdown menu is not working and why it's showing differently using other browsers? 
Is there a way on how to code CSS dropdown menu where it will show the same on any browser? Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats this: background-color: #FF0;ul#navmenu: hover a:hover

Comment: sorry, removed it, it doesn't have anything to do with it. still dropdown won't work, same result :(

Answer (score 3):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TcGQz/)

screen capture:

[image]

Use correct HTML buddy:

```
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And, add this CSS:

```
li ul{
    display:none;
}

li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Close the <li> tag after the end of the <ul> tag

Comment: i'm sorry are you pointing at "#" i don't understand when you said use the correct html?

Comment: I commented as well as to what I meant. I have also added the JSFIDDLE.

Comment: it's still not working using google chrome or IE. still won't show the dropdown menu :(

Comment: working for me in Chrome, please check. :) if not, I can provide you a demo from scratch

Comment: which IE version you're using ?

Comment: i'm gonna try to update it. sorry IE 7, what does li + li means in CSS? not familiar with it sorry :(

Comment: li + li means an li which is an immediate sibling for an li

Comment: li + li means sub of li? sorry i'm really new to this *scratches head

Comment: + is a way to select a sibling in CSS. if I say div + ul, that means I am trying to put css on ul which comes immediately after div in your html. similarly, li + li means that I am trying to put css on a <li> which comes immediately after an <li>. Think about this: using this rule, if i have 5 <li>'s immediately after each other, then this rule will apply css on all the <li> expect the first one becuase the first one does not come immediately after an <li>...I think this explanation will work if you read it carefully :)

Comment: got it, only li that comes after an li will adapat the rule of "li + li" ? is that correct? :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

please put ul in

submenu

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mh3ha/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}

    body
    {
        font-family: verdana;
        background-color: ABC;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    h1
    {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    /*rules for navigation menu */
    /*============================================*/
    ul#navmenu, ul.sub1
    {
        list-style-type: none;<!-- sets bullets to none -->

    }

    ul#navmenu li
    {

        width: 125px;
        text- align: center;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

    ul#navmenu a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block; <!-- this code makes the link a button instead  pointing specifically on the link -->
        width: 125px;
        height: 25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    ul#navmenu .sub1 li
    {

    }

    ul#navmenu .sub1 a 
    {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover > a
    {
     background-color: #CFC; <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover a: hover
    {
        background-color: #FF0;  <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
    }

    ul#navmenu ul.sub1
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        left: 0px;

    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1
    {
        display: block;
    }
li ul{
    display:none;
}

li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/vWDvy/)**

**[DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/ashrobbins/p7vfd/)**

Comment: it's still not working using google chrome or IE. still won't show the dropdown menu :(

Comment: @Daryl please try this demo2 (in my answer) IF its useful for you.

Comment: it's working in Google Chrome, but in IE it's not showing the dropdown menu for Drops?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things..

1.Correction in HTML, Where there is 'li' tag with child 'ul'with id="sub1".You need to write it as

```
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

// there was a typo mistake.You close 'li' before the 'ul'. It should be closed  in the end.

1. You need to display:none for sub1 menu.

   li ul{
       display:none;
   }
2. Then show it when you hover that 'li'

   li:hover ul{
       display:block;
   }

EDITED :Write this in style tag....

```
*{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;}

        body
        {
            font-family: verdana;
            background-color: ABC;
            padding: 50px;
        }

        h1
        {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        /*rules for navigation menu */
        /*============================================*/
        ul
        {
            list-style-type: none;<!-- sets bullets to none -->

        }

        ul#navmenu li
        {
            width: 125px;
            text- align: center;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 4px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        ul#navmenu a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block; <!-- this code makes the link a button instead  pointing specifically on the link -->
            width: 125px;                
            line-height: 25px;

        }
    ul#navmenu li:hover > a
        {
         background-color: #CFC; 
        }
    li ul{
        display:none;
        left: -40px;
        position: relative;
    }        
    li:hover ul{
        display:block;

    }
    ul#sub1 li:hover{
        background-color:red; 
    }
```

TRY IT

Comment: You're right, :D !!! i must be tired to not notice that.  I have another question, but i tried to add li ul{ display:none; } ,and li:hover ul{ display:block; }, still not working, but getting there! This one is not working for internet Explorer:(

Answer (score -1):

Your html is wrong use, `ul#sub1` should be child of `<li>`

```
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it is complete he is not a child, this was enough @Samuel

Comment: i'm confused i'm sorry... can you please lead me to the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the ul tag in Sub Menu.

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
    <ul id="sub1"> 
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
 *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}

    body
    {
        font-family: verdana;
        background-color: ABC;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    h1
    {
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    /*rules for navigation menu */
    /*============================================*/
    ul#navmenu, ul.sub1
    {
        list-style-type: none;<!-- sets bullets to none -->

    }

    ul#navmenu li
    {

        width: 125px;
        text- align: center;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

    ul#navmenu a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block; <!-- this code makes the link a button instead  pointing specifically on the link -->
        width: 125px;
        height: 25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    ul#navmenu .sub1 li
    {

    }

    ul#navmenu .sub1 a 
    {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover > a
    {
     background-color: #CFC; <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover a: hover
    {
        background-color: #FF0;  <!-- sets all link color when hovering to yellow  -->
    }

    ul#navmenu ul.sub1
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        left: 0px;

    }

    ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1
    {
        display: block;
    }
li ul{
    display:none;
}

li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Try This it will surely work...