# CSS dropdown menu in ie7 issue

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

here is my problem.
Everything is working except on ie7 (of course).
The dropdown menu don't display.

Do someone know a workaround?
FYI, the doctype is set. (If anybody ask)

Here is my code at the end...

Thanks for your help

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li class="subMenu">
                <a style='clear: left;' id='jiraMenu' href="#">JIRA</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Make a request</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#" >View the version</a></li>  <!--"https://caedsh03.caecorp.cae.com/secure/StructureBoard.jspa?s=173" !-->
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" name="language" >En</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.menu li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
}

.menu li a:link, .menu li a:visited {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#10509e;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    margin:0;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        color:white;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background-color:white; 
    color: #10509e;
    outline:1px solid black;
}

/*style the sub menu*/
.menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.menu li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:none;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu li ul li a:link, .menu li ul li a:visited {
    background-color:#10509e;   
    color: white;
    width:auto;
}

.menu > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    display: table-cell;
}

.menu li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:white; 
    color: #10509e;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Drop Down Menu Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310888/css-drop-down-menu-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

`display: table-cell` is not supported in IE7. Removing it should solve the problem.

http://jsbin.com/ugIfAJi/1